# Sharepoint beginner developer video tutorials

Tags: .net, c, vb.net, sharepoint

I do not know anything about SharePoint and we will be moving to SharePoint systems in a few months at work.

My manager told me I will be one of the developers developing systems based on SharePoint.

Is there any good video tutorials on SharePoint Development?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several online resources available out there. I would recommend starting at [Microsoft's Channel 9 site](http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/sharepoint?sort=viewed) for a ton of videos on Sharepoint, Silverlight, etc. From there you could check out:

- [Microsoft SharePoint Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/click/SharePointDeveloper/html/Default.html)
- [Sharepoint tutorials for developers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msftisvs/archive/2009/05/15/sharepoint-tutorials-for-developers.aspx)
- [Microsoft's official Sharepoint development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/aa905692)

[Google also comes up with all kinds of resources](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sharepoint%20developer%20tutorials) you could check out.

It's also worth mentioning that if you're going to be using SharePoint 2010, you should also take a look at [SilverLight](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/silverlight-4/) and how it [integrates with SharePoint 2010](http://www.sharepointmonitor.com/2010/03/getting-started-with-silverlight-in-sharepoint-2010/).